# How to query a system versioned table for recent changes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Clearly my understanding of the semantics of system versioned tables is wrong. I've tried a few things without success. Eg "between" and "contained in".

I have a system versioned table with a date column. It has the date that a record was inserted. But I want to query to get all records that were inserted or changed in the last 10 minutes, and so want to make use of the fact that this is a system versioned table. But I can't figure out the right way to formulate this query.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do as you would for querying any table with a `datetime2` column, for example you could do

```
select * from table
for system_time all
where SysValidFrom >= DateAdd(minute,-10,GetDate())
```

Note that `SysValidFrom` is the name of the system-versioned valid-from date - your column naming convention may vary.

Comment: Thanks. I had figured that out shortly after posting my question.
Now I have an add-on question. I had read that for such queries that it's faster to query the history table directly. But a colleague said that the history table wouldn't give the same results.

Comment: Well the only difference would be the history table won't include the *current* row. The above answers the question you asked, by all means ask this as a new question.

Comment: In my query, I had left out the "for system_time all" clause but it still seems to give me the answer I had expected. How would having that clause change things?

Comment: I just tried my query (following your pattern) both with and without "FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL" and I get the same (correct) answer. Is that because that's the default behavior?

Comment: Using `system_time all` effectively gives you a union of your main table and your history table. So if `select * from dbo.table where Column=1` gives you 50 rows and `select * from history.table where column=1` gives you 100 rows then  `select * from dbo.table for system_time all where Column=1` will return 150 rows